# How to add constant specific bytes to a routine that reads from buffer on arduino

Tags: arrays, string, arduino, communication, uart

I need to add a functionality to a code that i've already done.
I need to listen on **Serial1** (hardware port of arduino leonardo with bluetooth interface hooked up), and when there will come a string like that from external android device running come app that need UID:

```
(byte) 0xff, (byte) 0xca, (byte) 0x00, 0x00, (byte) 0x00 
getUID
```

I need to make that last routine in the code below to send a specific data:

The Construction of this routine must give me the ability to send as one string:

- First part: 4 bytes and the first byte of those 4 bytes must be "0x55" and next 3bytes might be just 0xFF,
- Second Part: there will be data from buffer that will contain the 4 or 7 bytes of serial number.
- Third part: 2 bytes where first is generic 0xff and the second must be 0xAA.

So the frame sent in response to the question should look like this:

**|0x55|0xFF|0xFF|0xFF|BUFFER|0xFF|0xAA|**

Could someone throw me a bone about how to accomplish that functionality within the sketch below ? I'm just starting my journey to the C/C++ world and i'm a bit frustrated.

```
 #include <SPI.h>
#include <MFRC522.h>
#include <Keyboard.h>

#define RST_PIN         9 
#define SS_PIN          10 

MFRC522 mfrc522(SS_PIN, RST_PIN);

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
    while (!Serial);
    Serial1.begin(9600);
    SPI.begin();
    mfrc522.PCD_Init();
}

void readFromBTSerial1() {                                
  if(Serial1.available() > 0) {
      incomingByte = Serial1.read()
       Push_dump_byte_array(mfrc522.uid.uidByte, mfrc522.uid.size);                  
  }
}   

void loop() {
    if ( ! mfrc522.PICC_IsNewCardPresent())
        return;

    if ( ! mfrc522.PICC_ReadCardSerial())
        return;

    Keyboard_dump_byte_array(mfrc522.uid.uidByte, mfrc522.uid.size);
    Bluetooth_dump_byte_array(mfrc522.uid.uidByte, mfrc522.uid.size);
    Serial_dump_byte_array(mfrc522.uid.uidByte, mfrc522.uid.size);
    Serial.println();
     // while  ( mfrc522.PICC_ReadCardSerial());
       mfrc522.PICC_HaltA();                                               
       mfrc522.PCD_StopCrypto1(); 
}

void Serial_dump_byte_array(byte *buffer, byte bufferSize) {
    for (byte i = 0; i < bufferSize; i++) {
        Serial.print(buffer[i] < 0x10 ? "0" : "");
        Serial.print(buffer[i], HEX);
    }
}

void Keyboard_dump_byte_array(byte *buffer, byte bufferSize) {
    for (byte i = 0; i < bufferSize; i++) {
        Keyboard.print(buffer[i] < 0x10 ? "0" : "");
        Keyboard.print(buffer[i], HEX);
    }
}

 void Bluetooth_dump_byte_array(byte *buffer, byte bufferSize) {
    for (byte i = 0; i < bufferSize; i++) {
        Serial1.print(buffer[i] < 0x10 ? "0" : "");
        Serial1.print(buffer[i], HEX);
    }
}

char Header[4] = {0x55, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF};
char Endpoint[2] = {0xFF, 0xAA};

void Push_dump_byte_array(byte *buffer, byte bufferSize) {                            

    for(int i = 0; i<4; ++i){
        Serial1.print(Header[i]);
    }
    for(byte i = 0; i < bufferSize; i++) {
        Serial1.print(buffer[i] < 0x10 ? "0" : "");
        Serial1.print(buffer[i], HEX);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i<2; ++i){
        Serial1.print(Endpoint[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you need to send `|0x55|0xFF|0xFF|0xFF|BUFFER|0xFF|0xAA|`, right?. You could do

```
// If you may need to change the values use global variables
char firstPart[4] = {0x55, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF};
char lastPart[2] = {0xFF, 0xAA};

void Push_dump_byte_array(byte *buffer, byte bufferSize) {
    for(int i = 0; i<4; ++i){
        Serial1.print(firstPart[i]);
    }
    for(byte i = 0; i < bufferSize; i++) {
        Serial1.print(buffer[i] < 0x10 ? "0" : "");
        Serial1.print(buffer[i], HEX);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i<2; ++i){
        Serial1.print(lastPart[i]);
    }
}
```

I just fixed the code, for(byte, and for(int

Comment: Yes that is exactly what i wanted to do,, the funny thing is that, doing in n a bit "not nice" way the effect was the same for the target software on android  device: i just used something like that:    Serial1.print("55FFFFFF");
    Push_dump_byte_array(mfrc522.uid.uidByte, mfrc522.uid.size);  
      Serial1.print("FFAA");, So i think that for that java application there is no difference between construction of the string.

Comment: One last thing to do now is to add a function that listens on Serial1, and when it gets the exact  data as requests from the java application from android device over UART: ((byte) 0xff, (byte) 0xca, (byte) 0x00, 0x00, (byte) 0x00 
getUID)   it sends back the data from Void Push_dump_byte_array() from the example already answered above.